# Java standardising List

Tags: java, arrays, list, standardized

Assume my code works. However, this little snippet of code:

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    myList.add(line.replaceAll ("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").toLowerCase());
}
```

is giving me this output:

```
a b c d
123
abcdz
456
aa
b
c
dd
```

Desired output:

```
abcd123abcdz456aabcdd
```

The code outputting this result is in a main method, and is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (args[i]));
                    List<String> foo = simplify(reader);
                        for (int j = 0; j < foo.size(); j++) {
                            System.out.println(foo.get(j));
                        }
                }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: you should trim spaces and newlines, that is all.

Comment: I understand that - however have little/no knowledge how to code this into my code

Comment: String s = ""; `s.replace(" ", "")` and `s.trim()`

Comment: Remove that space inside your regex and then output the list without putting line breaks between the elements...?

Comment: @KlemensMorbe has the Java answer. sheltem is right though. You've already got a regex. Just replace the \n and \r with "".

Comment: @mttdbrd I've managed to get rid of spaces, I dont want to use other methods in java or anything i need to keep the myList. In the regex how do I get rid of the \n happening at each new element? I can't work it out

Comment: There are no line breaks inside the elements. Those come from the output code. Without seeing that we can not advise on this part of your question.

Comment: @sheltem added it now

Comment: @user3364788 As I said in a comment to Erics answer: Use print() instead of println() for the output, since println() always finishes with a line break.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    String s = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").toLowerCase();
    myList.add(s);
    sb.append(s.trim());
}
```

Then print out `sb.toString()`.

`System.out.println(sb.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

`readLine` should disregard newlines.
can you show the code you are using for the output?

Comment: I dont want to use StringBuilder. The code outputting the result is for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (args[i]));
     List<String> foo = simplify(reader);
      for (int j = 0; j < foo.size(); j++) {
       System.out.println(foo.get(j));
      }
    }

Comment: Ah, there's your problem then. Using System.out.println means you *add* a line break after each element while generating the output. Use System.out.print() instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options,

```
// Add a trim call
myList.add(line.replaceAll ("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").toLowerCase().trim());
```

Or, call chain to replace

```
myList.add(line.replaceAll ("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").
    replace("\r", "").replace("\n","").toLowerCase());
```

Or perhaps you should extract that logic into a custom method entirely.

**EDIT**
add this,

```
if (foo.get(j) != null && foo.get(j).trim().length() > 0) {
  System.out.println(foo.get(j).trim());
}
```

Comment: I have tried both of these things, yet still new lines are being printed

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove all white space and generate a single `String` out of multiple input `Strings`:

```
// initializing StringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// iterating over lines read by Reader
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    // appending line to StringBuilder
    sb.append(line);
}

// printing StringBuilder toString lowercased with replaced white space
String result = sb.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");
System.out.println(result);
```